# How to get cards with his content perfectly alligned

Tags: html, css

I have this "cards" that works perfectly when they have the same content. But if I add content of different lengths, they all get messed up. What would be the best approach to fix this problem?

I have tried using a fixed height for the dark sections but I just can't make it work (the gray sections already have fixed height) because even if now the cards have the same height, the card with more content get higher for some reason.

This is how it looks if I add large content to one of them:

[image]

This what happens if I try to put a fixed height to the darker section:

[image]

This is my HTML and CSS without fixed height:
(I am not including the CSS for buttons, h4, etc)

```css
.bDivision,
.bNet,
.bPlacements,
.bGames-Wins {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 2em;
  margin-right: 1em;
  width: 300px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.container-boosts {
  max-width: 1300px;
}
.fBoosts .image {
  height: 400px;
  background-color: #595959;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #28F0FF;
}
.fBoosts .content {
  background-color: #1C1C1C;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="row container-boosts">
  <div class="bNet">
    <div class="image">
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <h4>Net Wins Boost</h4>
      <p>Some content some content some content some content</p>
      <a class="btn-choose">Purchase</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bDivision">
    <div class="image">
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <h4>Division Boost</h4>
      <p>Some content some content some content some content</p>
      <a class="btn-choose">Purchase</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bPlacements">
    <div class="image">
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <h4>Placements Boost</h4>
      <p>Some content some content some content some content Some content some content some content some content</p>
      <a class="btn-choose">Purchase</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bGames-Wins">
    <div class="image">
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <h4>Normal Games Boost</h4>
      <p>Some content some content some content some content</p>
      <a class="btn-choose">Purchase</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing to

```
.bDivision, .bNet, .bPlacements, .bGames-Wins  {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        margin-top: 2em;
        margin-right: 1em;
        width: 300px;
        display: inline-block;
        float: left;
    }
```

I was able to align on top the 4 divs with *id="content"*.

Answer (score 0):

Yes thats What u need....
A  `float : left ;`
in your 4 main divs seletor.